# Unicode characters in lstlisting

Tags: listings, unicode

I need to include code in the appendix of my thesis. The code contains comments and the compilation instantly breaks returning:

```
Unicode char �\lst@FillFixed@ (U+5A8)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
l.160       if (lastArg < 0, lastArg = 360° 
                                             + lastArg);
```

This is only one of many characters which produce problems. I cannot change my entire code just because this won't compile. Is there any way to include code with arbitrary unicode characters? Thank you.

**Edit:** complete sample code, as requested.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}


\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook} % one-sided


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  numbersep=9pt,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=true,
  showtabs=false,
  captionpos=b,
    literate={ö}{{\"o}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\lstinputlisting{code/power_series.html}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Relevant content of `power_series.html`:

```
if (lastArg < 0, lastArg = 360° + lastArg);
```

There really is not much to say about this problem. I only want to be able to use all unicode characters inside a listing. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: Your sample code can not be compiled. Add a full example or do you expect that we complete your snippets to test your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the Unicode character in the proper way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\protected\def\dg{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{05A8}{\dg}

\lstset{
    inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=true,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  numbersep=9pt,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=true,
  showtabs=false,
  captionpos=b,
  literate={ö}{{\"o}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1 {°}{\dg}1
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname.html}

\end{document}
```

The `\jobname.html` file contains

```
if (lastArg < 0, lastArg = 360° + lastArg);
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help. declaring unicode characters this way solves my problem.

Comment: Is not working with lualatex.

Comment: @Oromion `listings` has *many* problems with LuaLaTeX.