# Rendering unicode theta (θ) in lstlisting

Tags: listings, unicode

I am including some MATLAB code into my main document, using the listings package, which contains a unicode theta (θ). How can I render an actual unicode theta instead of using \theta. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
θ
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This returns the error "Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Search the site for the literate option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode characters in lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378600/unicode-characters-in-lstlisting)

Comment: Although it's been a while, I remember searching for the literate and found either that post or a similar one which solved my problem.