# Unicode characters with lstlisting

Tags: listings, utf8

In UTF-8 it should be possible to use ä and ö.

But actually in my code listing I use the package *listings* I receive by this example

```
\lstset{language=HTML}
 % Set your language (you can change the language for each code-block optionally)
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Socket Connection, frame=single]  % Start your code-block

// einbinden der Library mittels CommonJs
var net = require('net');

// Socket Client erstellen
var client = new net.Socket();

// mit dem Server verbinden IP Port angeben
client.connect(<PORT>, '<IP>', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

// verschiedene Events Listener
// dieser wird ausgelöst s der Server Daten zum Client sendet 
client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

\end{lstlisting}
```

the error message

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
```

And it is denoting to the line with the 'ö'
// dieser wird ausgelöst s der Server Daten zum Client sendet

*Note: Sure I know it isn't HTML but when I say JavaScript it doesn't work*

In the preamble I say

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Unicode Text
```

Comment: (1) please always provide a full example that others can copy and test as is. (2) listings does not really support UTF8 out of the box due to the way listings processes the contents. Which is why I gennerally advise our (Danish) students to always comment in English. You can use `literate` to add non-ascii to listings parsing, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411536/3929

Comment: Do umlauts work in the rest of your document? Perhaps this answer helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378600/unicode-characters-in-lstlisting But really, no way to tell without seeing your document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed) (I have posted an answer there with most European characters taken care of)

Comment: As also mentioned in some of the linked to questions, it can help switching to xelatex or lualatex that understands UTF8 natively

Comment: @Rmano yes it answers my question, thanks a lot :)